# How to convert libreoffice ODT to PDF in bash

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I am using libreoffice under CentOS 6. I can convert ODT files to PDF with:

`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt`
but the problem is that it only works when no document is open in libreoffice.

When I specify `--env:UserInstallation=file:///path/to/some/directory`
as suggested in one of the comments of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-convert-an-odt-file-to-a-pdf/104480#104480)  , it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong? It is a nuisance to close all libreoffice instances before running the before command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is unlikely going to work, as the suggestion in the comment is both incomplete (you cannot just specify some directory) and incorrect (`--env:...` should be `-env:..`. 
Here is what I recommend you do:

1. Stop all instances of libreoffice
2. Start libreoffice from the commandline without specifying `--headless`:

   ```
   libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///home/username/.config/libreoffice-alt
   ```

   you should replace `/home/username`  with your home directory (and adjust `.config` if you don't have that on your CentOS, I did this on Ubuntu and Linux Mint). The above will create a new configuration directory for the alternate libreoffice in your .config directory, without which you would get some error about java not being found.
3. Exit that instance of libreoffice
4. That directory `/home/username/.config/libreoffice-alt`  should now have been created for you.

Now start another `libreoffice` from the command-line (doing so allows you to see some useful messages if things go wrong when starting the second instance), without the `-env:...`, and while that is still running start the conversion using:

```
libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///home/username/.config/libreoffice-alt --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt
```

Comment: PS I have .config  as well on CentOS

Comment: Instead of stopping all instances, you can simply log in as a different user, create the .config-files and copy those to your own home dir.

Comment: On an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I just ran `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf <filename>.odt` and it did it, without those prep steps. It did print a warning about Java tho.

Answer (score 9):

One possible approach is to install `unoconv` (if not already installed) and

```
unoconv file.odt
```

Please see man `unoconv` for details

> `unoconv` is a command line utility that can convert any file format that LibreOffice can import, to any file format that
>          LibreOffice is capable of exporting.
>   `unoconv` uses the LibreOffice’s UNO bindings for non-interactive conversion....

In some platforms it is also necessary to install `libreoffice-headless` \thanks{Aaron}

Comment: Under CentOS7, I also had to add the package `libreoffice-headless` to have it automated. If the user has never used it before, the first call to `unoconv` fails with error 81 after creating a bunch of files in `~/.config/`.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, thank you very much for this important information! Probably there is a dependency missing in the spec file. I will add your tip to the answer.

Comment: @JJoao, if you are a CentOS user, you should report your finding as a bug report.

Comment: Not a spec dependency... just a use case. The error 81 issue [is supposedly fixed](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/192) but I don't know what version; I guess CentOS doesn't have it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a totally different approach.

It is possible, because in recent times a series of new conversion paths were opened by **[Pandoc's](https://pandoc.org/)** newly acquired capability to read ODT files.

When Pandoc reads in a file format, it converts it into an internal format, "native" (which is a form of JSON).

From its native form, it can then export the document into a whole range of other formats. Not only PDF, but also DocBook, HTML, EPUB, DOCX, ASCIIdoc, DokuWiki, MediaWiki and what-not...

Since here the wanted output format is PDF, we have another choice of different paths, provided by what Pandoc is calling a *pdf-engine*. Here is the list of currently available PDF engines (valid for Pandoc v2.7.2 and later -- previous versions may support only a smaller list):

- **pdflatex:** This requires *[LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **xelatex:** This requires *XeLaTeX* to be installed in addition to Pandoc (also available as an additional package to general [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)).
- **context:** This requires *ConTeXt* to be installed in addition to Pandoc; ConTeXt is available as an additional package to most general [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)).
- **lualatex:** This requires *[LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/download.html)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc (also available as an additional package to general [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#tex-distributions)).
- **pdfroff:** This requires *[GNU Roff](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/#downloading)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **wkhtml2pdf:** This requires *[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **prince:** This requires *[PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.
- **weasyprint:** This requires *[weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/)* to be installed in addition to Pandoc.

There are some more and newer PDF engines now integrated into Pandoc, which I have not yet used myself and which I currently cannot describe in more detail: *[tectonic](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5345)* and *[latexmk](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3195)*.

**WARNING:** Do not expect that the appearance of your original document will be identical in all the PDF outputs to the print preview or PDF export of the ODT! Pandoc, when converting ***does not preserve layouts***, it preserves the ***contents*** and the ***structure*** of documents: paragraphs remain paragraphs, emphasized words remain emphasized, headings remain headings, etc. But the overall look can change considerably.

#### Example commands

**pdflatex:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=pdflatex
```

**XeLaTeX:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=xelatex
```

**LuaLaTeX:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=lualatex
```

**ConTeXt:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=context
```

**GNU troff:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=pdfroff
```

**wkhtmltopdf:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=wkhtml2pdf
```

**PrinceXML:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=prince
```

**weasyprint:**

```
 pandoc -f odt -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.odt --pdf-engine=weasyprint
```

Above commands are the most basic for the conversion. Depending on the PDF engine you pick, there may be many other options possible to control the appearance of the output PDF file. For example, the following additional parameters may be added to all those paths routing through LaTeX:

```
 -V geometry:"paperwidth=23.3cm, paperheight=1000pt, margin=11.2mm, top=2cm"
```

which will use a custom page size (a bit larger than DIN A4) with margins of 2cm on the top edge and 1.12cm at the other three edges).

Comment: Unfortunately `pandoc` doesn't support every libreoffice format; for example `.ods` (the spreadsheet format) is not supported.

Comment: @Granitosaurus: The question was about ODT, hence this answer is appropriate.

Comment: Oh I never implied it wasn't appropriate, just that it's unfortunate pandoc doesn't support many other libreoffice formats.

Comment: @Granitosaurus: Pandoc is an OpenSource Software project. So you can easily contribute. If you're not into programming additional features into Pandoc, you at least can find their project on Github and are free to submit a *Feature Request* into their bug tracker. That also was what triggered Pandoc support for PowerPoint output to be added...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$ libreoffice2 pdf *.odt
```

Anyway, this pb. has been fixed the libreoffice Team since at least libreoffice 6.