# Convert .odt to .pdf on the command line - include automatically inserted blank pages

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

"[How to convert libreoffice ODT to PDF in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197063/how-to-convert-libreoffice-odt-to-pdf-in-bash/197072)" has a nice description of how to convert .odt to .pdf.

It does, however, not work if you want to check 'Export automatically inserted blank pages'.

How can I export ODT to PDF with the blank pages automatically inserted?

Answer (score 1):

if you only have access via terminal as I do, you have to add the following line in libreoffice's config file under the user folder that will be used to convert the odt files. In my case `/home/www-data/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`:

```
<item
  oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/Filter/PDF/Export"><prop
  oor:name="IsSkipEmptyPages"
  oor:op="fuse"><value>false</value></prop></item>
```